# How to set up Redis in custom namespace as cache and MQ on ServiceStack web application using Structuremap

Tags: redis, servicestack, structuremap

I want to set up my application to use Redis as Cache for sessions etc as well as run my Message Queues.

My application is a ASP.net MVC website along with ServiceStack based Json service provider. What is the optimal way to configure?

I want to be able to pass an IMessageQueueClient into my service classes and controllers so that I can add tasks to the queue.

I'm getting somewhat lost over what scope to make what. My code is as follows:

```
//Redis Client Manager
var pooledClientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RedisServer"));
pooledClientManager.NamespacePrefix = "myApp-";
For<IRedisClientsManager>().Singleton().Use(x => pooledClientManager);

//Cache
For<ICacheClient>().Use(c => c.GetInstance<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());

//MQ
MyApplication.MqService = new RedisMqServer(pooledClientManager);
For<IMessageQueueClient>().Singleton(). Use(
             x => MyApplication.MqService.CreateMessageQueueClient());
For<IMessageService>().Singleton().Use(x=>MyApplication.MqService);
```

I then later on call MyApplication.MqService.RegisterHandler(etc etc);

1. This works but I'm not convinced I've got my scoping correct.
2. The Namespace prefix doesn't work, and I need this feature.

Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NamespacePrefix` is only for internal data-structures maintained by the RedisClients and doesn't affect user-specified keys.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying that. I want to apply a new naming convention to redis objects, so that several apps could use same redis server. What is the simplest way to achieve that?

Also, any comment on the scoping I used with Structuremap - is it correct/optimal? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the same server instance the only real choice is to use different Db's. Otherwise you could create and use your own abstraction over the client which prefixes all keys with a custom prefix, similar to what you've suggested here.