# Consideration before creating a single Redis instance

Tags: redis

I currently have some different project that works on different redis instance ( consider the sample where I've 3 different asp.net application that are on different server each one with its redis server).
We've been asked to virtualize and to remove useless instances so I was wondering what happens if I have only one redis server and all the 3 asp.net points to the same redis instance.

For the application key I think there's no problem, I can prefix my own key with the application name , for example "fi-agents", "ga-agents", and so on... but I was wondering for the auth session what happens?

as far as I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095348/how-to-set-up-redis-in-custom-namespace-as-cache-and-mq-on-servicestack-web-appl) the Prefix is used as internal and it can't be used by final user to separate... it's just enought to use [different Db](http://www.rediscookbook.org/multiple_databases.html)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally and unless there are truely compelling reasons, you don't want to mix different applications and their data in the same database. Yes, it does lower ops costs initially but it can quickly deteriorate to scaling and performance nightmare. This, I believe, is true for any database.

Specifically with Redis, technically yes - you could use a key prefix or the shared/numbered database approach. I'm not sure what you meant by "auth" sessions but you can probably apply the same approach to them. But you really shouldn't... since Redis is a single-threaded process you can end up where one of the apps is blocking the other two. Since Redis by itself is so lightweight, just spin up dedicated servers - one per app - even in the same VM if you must. You can read more background information on why you don't want to opt for the shared approach here: https://redislabs.com/blog/benchmark-shared-vs-dedicated-redis-instances

Comment: I completely agreed with Itamar, instead using a single Redis instance (instance == process not server), it's better divide the load into multiple Redis instances in the same server (listening on different ports: 6379, 6380, 6381). I would recommend to completely avoid the use of multiple DBs in the same instance. Shared Redis instances lack a lot on performance by my personal experience.